# when click on row showing error IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## test.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
import sqlite3 as lite
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window    
Window.size = (900, 500)



MAX_TABLE_COLS = 3

con = lite.connect('demo.db')
con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()

class EditStatePopup(Popup):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?"])
    index = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditStatePopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.index = obj.index
        self.col_data[0] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Id"]
        self.col_data[1] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Name"]
        self.col_data[2] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Code"]

    def package_changes(self, stateName, stateCode):
        self.col_data[1] = stateName
        self.col_data[2] = stateCode


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    rv_data = ObjectProperty(None)
    start_point = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SelectableButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .0005)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = self.rv_data[self.index][self.key]

    def on_press(self):
        popup = EditStatePopup(self)
        popup.open()

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        self.rv_data = rv.data
        #print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[1]))

class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    col1 = ListProperty()
    col2 = ListProperty()
    col3 = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_states()

    def update(self):
        self.col1 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'Code': x[2], 'key': 'Id'} for x in self.data_items]
        self.col2 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'Code': x[2], 'key': 'Name'} for x in self.data_items]
        self.col3 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'Code': x[2], 'key': 'Code'} for x in self.data_items]

    def get_states(self):

        rows = [(1, 'Yash', 'Chopra'), (2, 'amit', 'Kumar')]
        # create data_items

        i = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.data_items.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], i])
            i += 1
        self.update()

class CustDrop(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustDrop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.select('')

class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    rv = ObjectProperty(None)
    states = ObjectProperty(None)
    dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_states(self):
        self.dropdown.dismiss()
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.rv = RV()
        self.states.add_widget(self.rv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.states.children]:
            self.states.remove_widget(child)

    def update_states(self, obj):
        # update data_items
        # obj.start_point + 1 --- skip State_ID
        self.rv.data_items[obj.index] = [ obj.col_data[0], obj.col_data[1], obj.col_data[2], obj.index]
        self.rv.update()
        # update Database Table
        cur.execute("UPDATE m_state SET state_name=?, state_code=? WHERE state_id=?",
                (obj.col_data[1], obj.col_data[2], obj.col_data[0]))
        con.commit()

class TestApp(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return MainMenu()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import CoreImage kivy.core.image.Image
#:import os os

<EditStatePopup>:
    title: "Update State"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 300, 300
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Id"
            Label:
                id: Id
                text: root.col_data[0]
            Label:
                text: "Name"
            TextInput:
                id: Name
                text: root.col_data[1]
            Label:
                text: "Code"
            TextInput:
                id: stateCode
                text: root.col_data[2]

            Button:
                size_hint: 1, 0.4
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.dismiss()

            Button:
                size_hint: 1, 0.4
                text: "Ok"
                on_release:
                    root.package_changes(Name.text, Code.text)
                    #root.obj.update_states(root.start_point, root.max_table_cols, root.new_data)
                    app.root.update_states(root)
                    root.dismiss()



<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1) if self.selected else (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<MyRV@RecycleView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
    SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        default_size: None, dp(26)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .1
                text: "Id"
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .5
                text: "Name"
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "Code"

        BoxLayout:
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .1
                data: root.col1
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .5
                data: root.col2
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .4
                data: root.col3


<DropdownButton@Button>:
    border: (0, 16, 0, 16)
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '30dp'
    #on_release: dropdown.select('')
    #on_release: app.root.test
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1


#<CustDrop>:
    #id: dropdown
    #auto_width: False
    #width: 150
    #DropdownButton:
        #text: 'Add State'
        #on_release: os.system("python m_State.py")

    #DropdownButton:
        #text: 'List State'
        #on_release: root.display_users()

<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (80,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)


<MainMenu>:
    states: states
    dropdown: dropdown

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 1

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Menu'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: dropdown.open(self)

            CustDrop:
                id: dropdown
                auto_width: False
                width: 150

                DropdownButton:
                    text: 'user'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '32dp'
                    #on_release: dropdown3.open(self)
                    on_release: root.display_states()

        BoxLayout:
            id: states
            size_hint_y: 9

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 9
```

1. When i click on menu then show sub menu user.when click on user then show list of user when i click on any row of user then show error IndexError: list index out of range.
2. update_states() function does not update in database

Comment: You have forgotten to import `Clock`: `from kivy.clock import Clock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.When i click on menu then show sub menu user.when click on user then show list of user when i click on any row of user then show error like attached image.

You are iterating over rows, you have only two rows but 3 columns

> 2. update_states() function does not update in database

I don't think that the compilator terminates that function because there are few errors in it

To get your code works I had to make many changes

First prepare the data of the rvs in the python file

```
...

class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    col1 = ListProperty()
    col2 = ListProperty()
    col3 = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_states()

    def update(self):
        self.col1 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'Code': x[2], 'key': 'Id'} for x in self.data_items]
        self.col2 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'Code': x[2], 'key': 'Name'} for x in self.data_items]
        self.col3 = [{'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'Code': x[2], 'key': 'Code'} for x in self.data_items]

    def get_states(self):

        #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `m_state` order by state_id asc")
        #rows = cur.fetchall()
        rows = [(1, 'Yash', 'Chopra'), (2, 'amit', 'Kumar')]
        # create data_items
        '''for row in rows:
            for col in row:
                self.data_items.append(col)'''
        i = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.data_items.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], i])
            i += 1
        self.update()

...
```

then in the kv replace the data of the rvs by col1, col2, col3 respectively

```
...

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .1
                text: "Id"
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .5
                text: "Name"
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "Code"

        BoxLayout:
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .1
                data: root.col1
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .5
                data: root.col2
            MyRV:
                size_hint_x: .4
                data: root.col3

...
```

To change automatically the text of the buttons of the rvs when you edit them I had to schedule a function

```
...

class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    rv_data = ObjectProperty(None)
    start_point = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SelectableButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .0005)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = self.rv_data[self.index][self.key]

...

    def on_press(self):
        popup = EditStatePopup(self)
        popup.open()

...
```

You have also to edit the `EditStatePopup`, I add the index attribute because It will be much easier to make change in the mainmenu with him

```
...

class EditStatePopup(Popup):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?"])
    index = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditStatePopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.index = obj.index
        self.col_data[0] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Id"]
        self.col_data[1] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Name"]
        self.col_data[2] = obj.rv_data[self.index]["Code"]
```

Finally edit the `updtate_states` of the `MainMenu` class:

```
...

class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
...
    def update_states(self, obj):
        # update data_items
        # obj.start_point + 1 --- skip State_ID
        self.rv.data_items[obj.index] = [ obj.col_data[0], obj.col_data[1], obj.col_data[2], obj.index]
        self.rv.update()
        # update Database Table
        cur.execute("UPDATE m_state SET state_name=?, state_code=? WHERE state_id=?",
                (obj.col_data[1], obj.col_data[2], obj.col_data[0]))
        con.commit()
```

Please be careful when making those changes. I hope this helps

Comment: i have edited code.I don't know where i am making mistake. Please can you take a look?